# Scrolling Indicator Gets Stuck When Bouncing Is Disabled for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have this problem, and I can't find any other mention of this anywhere.

Basically, if I disable bouncing in a UIScrollView (so derivatives such as UITableView are also affected) it's possible to get the scroll indicator stuck if a user scrolls to the top, and then, with another gesture, tries to continue scrolling using a quick swipe.

Once this happens, the scroll indicator will not disappear unless a user scrolls again or taps the scrollview. The biggest issue is that the scrollview will capture that tap and so if you try to tap on say a table cell, nothing will happen the first time.

I've tested this with just a barebones app on both my device and the simulator, and it seems to just be a general issue with UIScrollView and disabling bouncing; however, like I said I can't find any other mention of this on the internet.

Is this just a bug? Is this expected behavior? Am I doing something wrong? If this is a bug, then does anyone know of a work-around or fix?

Comment: I have the same, or a similar problem right now. I guess I will enable bouncing for now... As you say, when this problem occurs, the next tap will be "swallowed" by the table view, so that a cell has to be tapped two times in order to be selected etc.

Comment: Hi guys, did you find a solution to this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: This bug (or feature, whatever) still remains in iOS 11, 5 years later. The only "fix" I know, I guess is to enable `.bounces`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had two `UIScrollView` s, one nested inside the other. 
When inner **scroll view** reached the top, I forcibly set the `contentOffset.y` to `0` (I need this to allow outer scroll view begin scrolling its content view). This caused the **scroll view** undesired behavior described in this **question**.

The fix was setting the `contentOffset.y` to `-1`, which allowed the scroll view scroll back to **0** naturally (by itself), and the hung behavior was *dismissed*.

Hope this helps the others ✋

Answer (score 0):

Have you added tap gesture for your scrollview, if not then try adding it?

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(resignsKeyboard)];
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.delegate = self;
```

Add delegate UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in your interface file then implement the tap gesture delgate method

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
 if (self.scrollView.superview != nil)
    {
        if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]||[touch.view.superview.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]||[touch.view.superview.superview.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]||[touch.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            // we touched our control surface
        {
            return NO; // ignore the touch
        }

    }

    return YES; // handle the touch
}
```

//To perform other actions on scroll touch like resigning keyboard, use if needed

```
-(void) resignsKeyboard
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];
}
```